# Cannot figure out whats wrong with this code

Tags: php, html

Could someone please tell me whats wrong with this code because I cannot find anything?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Meine Seite</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Willkommen</h2>
<br />
<?php
define("EZSQL_DB_USER", 'xxxxx_xxxx');
define("EZSQL_DB_PASSWORD", 'xxxxxxx');
define("EZSQL_DB_NAME", 'xxxx_xxxx');
define("EZSQL_DB_HOST", 'localhost');
if (!function_exists('gettext')) {
function _($s) {return $s;}
}
?>
<?php
$mysqlConnection = mysql_connect(EZSQL_DB_HOST, EZSQL_DB_USER, EZSQL_DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$mysqlConnection)
{
echo "<h2>Hallo du!</h2>";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

The result:

```
Willkommen

Hallo du!"; } ?>
```

Your help is very much appreciated!

thanks

Comment: Is it `echo`ing or not? What's happening? We need this information to help you.

Comment: what error do you see when you are trying to load that page?

Comment: yes but this<h2>Hallo du!</h2>";
}

?>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nTqp7/ ?????

Comment: @Chriswede: could you add the *expected* result to your question, i.e. what you expect to see as output? I assume it’s `Willkommen Hallo du!`, but you need to state that.

Comment: Are you actually ***executing the file as PHP script?!*** It doesn't look like you are...

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL|~E_STRICT);`  at the top of the file. Then paste the output here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Hallo du!"; } ?>`

That shows your php is not running. You have to upload the php file to a webserver Then see from browser. Like `http://localhost/file.php`. **Not** as `C:\documents\file.php`

Comment: You could use this http://www.wampserver.com/en/ for development if you are on Windows. Is is easy to install.